# Maximum water extent JRC dataset

Tags: google-earth-engine, flood

I am trying to map the maximum water extent in a certain area. Therefore I thought to use the JRC dataset by using the 'max_extent' band. The code however gives me the following error: "max_extent" is not defined in this scope.
The 'max_extent' band is binary instead of for instance the 'occurrence' band.

1. Is there something wrong in my code?
2. How to visualize the binary 'max_extent' band?
3. Is the JRC datset suitable for this task, or should I use another method?

[image: console_error]

```js
// ------MAXIMUM EXTENT------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var gsw = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_0/GlobalSurfaceWater');
print(gsw);

var occurrence = gsw.select('max_extent');

var VIS_OCCURRENCE = {
  min:0,
  max:100,
};

Map.addLayer({
  eeObject: occurrence.updateMask(max_extent.divide(100)),
  name: "Maximum Water Extent (1984-2015)",  
  visParams: VIS_OCCURRENCE
});
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which stresses the importance of asking one question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question so there is one question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, 'max_extent' is not defined in your scope. Check your code, there isn't any object called `max_extent`
2. `Map.addLayer(gsw.select('max_extent'))`
3. Is unclear the aim of your analysis, please be clear. If you want *the maximum water extent in a certain area*, just use max extent instead occurrence layer.

Comment: Thanks! In the end it turned out to be the '.divide(100)' part which was interfering.